# Displaying Select Rows from Multiple SQL Tables in an MVC Project

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I have an MVC program that is uploading data from a .csv file to a SQL database. I am now trying to display the data uploaded with a WebGrid table.  All the examples that I have seen demonstrate only displaying one complete table at a time.

I am new to using MVC and WebGrid, so first of all I was wondering if this was the right approach to this problem, and secondly, if this approach is the best route, how will I have to set up the Views to display data from 3 different tables. Will it require 3 different controllers & 3 different views, and will I have to have multiple Data Models? Any input would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some MVC best practices:

***Your view model should be what you want to display on the view***
This seems obvious, but at first it is not.  Start by creating your view model, and when you're doing that assume that you know **nothing** about your data store.

***Your view model should not know/care how your data is stored***
The view's job is just to display some data, that is all.  Your view model should be something like this:

```
public class ViewModel123 {
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string foo {get;set;}//this may come from table A or table B, it does not matter
   public string bar {get;set;}//this may come from table A or table B, it does not matter
}
```

***Create a data access layer***

This is the layer that gets data out of the database from N number of tables.  Assuming you're using EF or linq-to-sql the method to get the data would look something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ViewModel123> GetData() {
   return DatabaseHande.SomeThing.Select(x=> new ViewModel123 {
   ID = x.id,
   Foo = x.Foo,
   Bar = x.LinkTable.Bar
});
}
```

***Have your controller call your data access layer and return the view model***

You controller can now call the data access layer and return the view model to the view.  More pseudo code:

```
public ActionResult List() {
   var viewModelDataRows = _dataAccessClass.GetData();
   return View(viewModelDataRows);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. One last thing though, when making the View, I do not need an '@using model statement', correct?

Comment: At the top of the view you would have @model IEnumerable<ViewModel123>